# How to create a bidirectional link between containers?

Tags: docker

I have to link two containers so they can see each other. Of course the following...

```
docker run -i -t --name container1 --link container2:container2 ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
docker run -i -t --name container2 --link container1:container1 ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
```

...fails at line 1 because a container needs to be up and running in order to be a link target:

```
2014/08/15 03:20:27 Error response from daemon: Could not find entity for container2
```

What is the simplest way to create a bidirectional link?

Comment: My recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname/30550990#30550990) may interest you.

Comment: thanks, this is actually what I did as well (see my own answer below), and it's been working very reliably

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Docker 1.10 addresses this very nicely by introducing advanced container networking.
(Details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/ )

First, create a network. The example below creates a basic "bridge" network, which works on one host only. You can check out docker's more complete documentation to do this across hosts using an overlay network.

```
docker network create my-fancy-network
```

Docker networks in 1.10 now create a special DNS resolution inside of containers that can resolve the names in a special way. First, you can continue to use --link, but as you've pointed out your example doesn't work. What I recommend is using --net-alias= in your docker run commands:

```
docker run -i -t --name container1 --net=my-fancy-network --net-alias=container1 ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
docker run -i -t --name container2 --net=my-fancy-network --net-alias=container2 ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
```

Note that having --name container2 is setting the container name, which also creates a DNS entry and --net-alias=container2 just creates a DNS entry on the network, so in this particular example you could omit --net-alias but I left it there in case you wanted to rename your containers and still have a DNS alias that does not match your container name.

(Details here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/ )

And here you go:

```
root@4dff6c762785:/# ping container1
PING container1 (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from container1.my-fancy-network (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from container1.my-fancy-network (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from container1.my-fancy-network (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
```

And from container1

```
root@4f16381fca06:/# ping container2
PING container2 (172.19.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from container2.my-fancy-network (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from container2.my-fancy-network (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
64 bytes from container2.my-fancy-network (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
```

Comment: Is there any way to set it in docker compose?

Comment: Excellent solution

Answer (score 14):

There is no bi-directional link since  you can not link to a non-running container.

Unless you are [disabling inter-container communication](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#between-containers), all containers on the same host can *see* any other containers on the network. All you need is to provide them the ip address of the container you want to contact.

The simplest way of knowing the ip address of a container is to run:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container1
```

You can look it up after starting both containers (just don't use `--link`).

If you need to know the IP of *container2* from inside *container1* automatically, there are a few options:

1. Mount the docker socket as a volume and use the remote API

   docker run -i -t --name container1 -v /var/run/docker.sock:docker.sock ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
   echo -e "GET /containers/container2/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /docker.sock | sed 's/.*IPAddress":"([0-9.]*).*/\1/'
2. Use an orchestration service… there are so many to choose from, but I personally like the DNS-based ones like [Skydock](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock) or [registrator](https://github.com/progrium/registrator) and access containers by dns name.
3. Use a docker management service (such as dockerize.it —disclaimer: I am working on it—) that will setup the DNS services for you.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer! I will leave this question open for a little while and see if there may be another suggestion.

Comment: About suggestion "1" - why do you run a Docker container just to `echo -e "GET...\r\n"`?

Comment: That example cover the case that «you need to know the IP of container2 from inside container1». That means you already started the container for some other reason.

Answer (score 14):

Since there is no bidirectional link I solved this issue with the [--net](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) argument. That way they are using the same network stack and can therefore access each other over the loopback device (localhost).

```
docker run -d --name web me/myserver
docker run -d --name selenium --net container:web me/myotherserver
```

So I can access from web the selenium server (port 4444) and my selenium server can access my web server (port 80).

Comment: how did you know the value of 4444 and 80?

Comment: @Richard the ports were just due to the fact that I had a webserver and a selenium server running within the containers. There is no need to specify the ports with this solution. Whatever ports are open within one container are available in the other container.

Comment: genius! I spent hours looking for this!

Comment: How do you get IP of other server?

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I've solved this for myself:

First, I go through all my containers (which need to know from each other) and create dnsmasq entries like so:

```
for f in container1 container2 container3; do
  IP=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $f 2>/dev/null`
  if [ -n "$IP" ]; then
    echo $f "$IP"
    echo "host-record=$f,$IP" > /etc/dnsmasq.d/0host_$f
  else
    rm -f /etc/dnsmasq.d/0host_$f
  fi
done
```

Then I start a dns container which has dnsmasq-base installed and starts the dnsmasq service:

```
docker run -d -P -h dns --name dns -v /etc/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d:ro dns
```

then I get the IP address of this container:

```
DNS_IP=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' dns`
```

And start the containers like so:

```
docker run -d -P -h container1 --name container1 --dns $DNS_IP container1
docker run -d -P -h container2 --name container2 --dns $DNS_IP container2
docker run -d -P -h container3 --name container3 --dns $DNS_IP container3
```

This is a simplified version of my setup but it shows the gist. I've also added a mechanism that forces dnsmasq to rescan when files in /etc/dnsmasq.d change via inotify-tools. That way all containers get the new ip address whenever one container is restarted.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by appending an ip-table into /etc/hosts of each container, for 
[example](https://github.com/Wei1234c/dockerfiles/blob/master/ARMv7/hadoop/cluster/start.sh)

Comment: Oh, I just found out that Docker version 1.8.1 will register and bridge each running containers automatically in each other's /etc/hosts file, so no need for further configuration.

Comment: it works! this is excellent! could your rephrase your answer? I will accept it as the new correct answer.