# docker linking how can both containers know each others ip

Tags: docker

From the docker linking

I can have A container links to B container.

Then I can see the B's ip address and exposed port in A's ENV variables.

However, how can I figure out A's ip address wihtin B container?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a bidirectional link between containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324860/how-to-create-a-bidirectional-link-between-containers)

Comment: I didn't know "Then I can see the B's ip address and exposed port in A's ENV variables." so thanks for solving my problem, even though it was the question and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find one container from another, you can use a 'service discovery' mechanism such as [SkyDock](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock).

> ### Skydock - Automagic Service Discovery for Docker
>
> Skydock monitors docker events when containers start, stop, die, kill, etc and inserts records into a dynamic DNS server skydns. This allows standard DNS queries for services running inside docker containers.

For the more complex case where your containers are on multiple hosts and you need a way to network them together, see [weave-dns](https://github.com/zettio/weave/tree/master/weavedns)  (Please note I work on weave and weave-dns).