# Update hosts file in all containers

Tags: docker

Is there anyway I can get Docker to update the /etc/hosts of all containers?

I want each container running on the host machine to know the hostname of all other containers running on the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use next approach: use own dns server (dnsmasq is easy choice) and update it with addresses of all running containers dynamically (either via polling or using docker events). Here couple of samples: [1](https://www.npmjs.org/package/docker-dns), [2](http://www.labouisse.com/how-to/2014/11/30/dynamic-dns-update-for-docker-containers/), [3](http://objectiveoriented.com/devops/2014/02/15/docker-io-service-discovery-your-network-and-how-to-make-it-work/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It is automatically done when you link the containers:
https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#updating-the-etchosts-file

Comment: I tried this but only the parent container knows the child containers hostname. The child container doesn't know the parents hostname. The link is one way it seems.

Comment: hmmmm see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324860/how-to-create-a-bidirectional-link-between-containers

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048319/docker-linking-how-can-both-containers-know-each-others-ip/27067586#27067586

Answer (score 0):

You can try using weave, which is a project I am working on. It gives you an [overlay network with DNS](https://github.com/zettio/weave/blob/master/weavedns/README.md), so you can forget about the hosts files, linked containers and most of those things.