# docker network link to 2 or multiple containers

Tags: docker, port

As per [docker link docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) I can only --link to one (already running) container to access internal ports of that container.

How can I link one container to 2 or more other containers? (MongoDB and another web service in my case.)

(Right now I am exposing ports of second container to host and then accessing via host:port, also possible workaround might be [Let two Containers getting linked to eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563460/let-two-containers-getting-linked-to-eachother) .)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname/30550990#30550990

Comment: I guess you can use --link multiple times to link to multiple containers. I have used the same many times.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
docker run -d --link node1:node1 --link node2:node2 --link node3:node3 -p hostport:containerport your-image
```

I run the command above and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can turn on inter-container communication by adding --icc=true to the docker daemon's command-line, and you won't have to link the containers, just access them using the Docker Host's IP address and the containers' published ports.

[Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#communication-between-containers)

Answer (score 1):

For an easy solution you could use `Docker-compose`. in you compose file (docker-compose.yml) use the option `links`
Link to containers in another service. Either specify both the service name and a link alias (SERVICE:ALIAS), or just the service name.

```
container_name:
links:
      - node1
      - node2
      - node3:alias3
      - noden
```