# Adding a backup crontab into a docker container

Tags: docker, backup, cron

I want to implement backup tasks for my docker containers using crontab

Question :

- Is it a nice way to implement backup task of a docker containers ?
- How do you add a crontab ? Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run cron as a main purpose of the container than fine, look at some older questions:

- [How do I start cron on docker ubuntu base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545554/how-do-i-start-cron-on-docker-ubuntu-base)
- [Cron containers for docker - how do they actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847019/cron-containers-for-docker-how-do-they-actually-work)

If you want to run it as side task (as cron usually run), I would reconsider going with first option :)