# Backup Mongo in a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker, backup, docker-cloud

I have deployed an Mongo image in a Docker container via Docker Cloud. It is linked to a Meteor app. Is there any way to backup the data on the container?

Answer (score 0):

Create another Docker container that runs a script controlled by a cron job that executes the backup and stores it onto a shared volume.

Also  see [Cron containers for docker - how do they actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847019/cron-containers-for-docker-how-do-they-actually-work)