# Execution commands between two dockers containers

Tags: docker

I wonder if it's possible to exec commands between two containers (docker exec -it  )?

I have a container running Jenkins and another one with my web application, after the build I want that the Jenkins Container send commands directly to the project container. I would like to avoid to use ssh. Is it possible?

Comment: see some ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the docker socket from host to the container you want to run command with. See https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337