# Cannot insert data to TDengine server that started within Docker

Tags: docker, tdengine

Currently I'm using the command `docker run -p 6030-6042:6030-6042/tcp -p 6030-6040:6030-6040/udp --name taosd tdengine/tdengine` to start a TDengine server, and then connect it with `taos` shell in another container with `docker run --rm -it tdengine/tdengine taos -h <host ip>`. It connects ok, but when inserting data into a table, it causes error:

```
Welcome to the TDengine shell from Linux, Client Version:2.0.22.0
Copyright (c) 2020 by TAOS Data, Inc. All rights reserved.

taos> create database if not exists test;
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.000638s)

taos> use test;
Database changed.

taos> create table if not exists tb1 (ts timestamp, n int);
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.000880s)

taos> insert into tb1 values (now, 1);

DB error: Unable to resolve FQDN (0.090774s)
```

Comment: You shouldn't usually need the host IP here.  Do the techniques in [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname) help?  (If you `docker run --net` both containers on the same network, you can use the `taosd` container name as a host name from the client container; ignore the very old answers about Docker links.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDengine connecting is based on FQDN(hostname if it familiar to you) - which requires DNS resolution for the server end point).

In your case, first set the hostname in start: `docker run --hostname taosd ...`, and then `echo <your ip> taosd >> /etc/hosts` in your shell located container or host. then you can connect it with `taos -h taosd` (here we use taosd as the TDengine server container hostname, all the connections should use hostname to resolve the real ip.)

Steps:

1. start TDengine server:

   ```sh
   docker run --rm --hostname taosd \
     -p 6030-6042:6030-6042/tcp -p 6030-6040:6030-6040/udp \
     --name taosd tdengine/tdengine
   ```
2. start another container as client:

   ```sh
   docker run --rm -it --add-host taosd:<your ip> tdengine/tdengine taos -h taosd
   ```

   `--add-host` will add an dns resolvation line in /etc/hosts.

   `<your ip>` you could use the external IP or get the container ip by `docker inspect taosd |jq '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks[].IPAddress' -r`.
3. now insert data with your sql:

   ```
   create database if not exists test;
   use test;
   create table if not exists tb1 (ts timestamp, n int);
   insert into tb1 values (now, 1);
   ```

All done.