# how to communicate between two containers: nginx and nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, next.js, podman

Ii'm having a hard time figuring out how to `proxypass` into a `nodejs` container from a `nginx` container.

seems to me that `http://localhost:3000` would fall inside the `nginx` container...so I thought this setup would make sense:

**`nginx` container:**

```
podman run -d \
            --name nginx.main \
            -p 0.0.0.0:8081:8080 \
            -p 0.0.0.0:4431:4430 \
            -p 0.0.0.0:3001:3000 \
            -u root \
            -v /home/_secrets/certbot/_certs:/etc/nginx/_cert \
            -v /home/mee/_volumes/nginx_main:/etc/nginx \
            nginx
```

**`nodejs` container:**

```
podman run -d \
            -v /home/mee/dev/abd/:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app \
            -p 3000:3000 \
            --name next.dev node:latest \
            npm run dev
```

**`firewalld`, routing from `3001` to `3000`:**

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3001/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent \
   --zone=mee_fd \
   --add-forward-port=port=3001:proto=tcp:toport=3000
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

**`nginx` config:**

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }
```

really not sure how this should communicate... I've tried using the `ipaddress` instead of 'localhost', but I get the same response.

thanks

Comment: In a pure Docker context, see [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname).  I'm not sure if Podman has the same networking setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze you can create a bridge network, which is what i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow communication between containers you need to setup a shared networks, e.g. in .yaml (this can be done as well as on ci, report in .yaml only for sake of code):

```
version: '2'
services:
proxy:
build: ./
networks:
- example1
- example2
ports:
- 80:80
- 443:443

networks:
example1:
external:
name: example1_default
example2:
external:
name: example2_default
```

Then in your nginx config:

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://myServiceName:3000; <-- note is not localhost but the name of node service
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }
```

Let me know

Comment: can i do something like this:
```upstream app {server linodeipaddress:3000; }
```
```location / {#proxy_pass http://app;#proxy_set_header Host website.com;}
```

Comment: (If you are using Compose, [it provides a network for you automatically](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you don't need any of the manual `networks:` blocks.  Do double-check the indentation of the YAML file, it is critical for the file to work correctly.)