# docker: Error response from daemon: network cassandra not found

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am following the guide given on the official website(https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html) I don't have much experience with docker so I need help, what can I do to make this work.

first I run this

```
docker run --name cassandra cassandra
```

2nd

```
docker run --rm -d --name cassandra_host --hostname cassandra_host --network cassandra cassandra
```

and I get the below error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network Cassandra not found.
```

Comment: You need to [`docker network create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) the network first.  You might look at [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname) for a little more context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're sorry about this. This is an error in our docs and we have a scheduled update to the site soon to fix this ([CASSANDRA-17485](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17485)).

In the meantime, the command to create a Docker network is:

```
$ docker network create cassandra
```

Then you should be able to start the container with:

```
docker run --rm -d 
  --name cassandra 
  --hostname cassandra 
  --network cassandra 
  cassandra
```

Cheers!