# Communication link failure on Docker container: Spring boot, MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

After search on stackoverflow feels like it is common problem, but I didn't found the decision.

Without docker the program works on localhost.
The docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/DockerMyBlog.jar DockerMyBlog.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "DockerMyBlog.jar"]
```

The application.properties (did attempt to replace "localhost" over here for "dockermyblog"):

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javastudy
jdbc.username=hey
jdbc.password=hey
```

Creating container by command in terminal:

```
docker build -t dockermyblog .
```

Trying to launch it by:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 dockermyblog
```

Receive an error:

```html
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449)
......................
```

Tried to set (without understanding what's that):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javastudy?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

or

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://dockermyblog:3306/javastudy?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Tried to put in terminal:

```
docker inspect dockermyblog | grep IPAddress
```

Terminal does not know "grep"

What should I do to launch it locally

Comment: Is you Mysql DB available at `localhost:3306`? Are you able to connect to it with any DB client?

Comment: yes. If I launch it as usual from IDEA, the program works in browser http://localhost:8080 and receives data from DB

Comment: I think that MySQL listen localhost only and it see docker container dockermyblog has another server. May be do a docker-compose with 2 containers : mysql and dockermyblog

Comment: could you give a link with instructions how to do it? I'm very-very newbie in all that.

Comment: Is your MySQL dockerized?

Comment: Found some explanations over here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck6xQqSOlpw As it is explained up there, I've created image "mysql" (...feels like it should automatically grab my DB..?). Now I have 2 images: mysql and dockermyblog. Do I correctly understand that I need now create "docker-compose.yml" where it will be joined in one container? That is the way?

Comment: The linked question has some complete examples of running a Spring application and a database in a single Compose file.  In Docker, `localhost` will generally refer to your application container and not the database.  If you want to run the two containers side-by-side without Compose, also see [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname).

Comment: OK. Thank you. Feels like we can close this question and I need to go and learn some more about "docker-compose.yml" Guy's, thank you to all for directing me!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `localhost` in the Java application like this, it resolves to the address on the *container* and no on the *host* (so your computer). Since there is no MySQL server running in the same container it will fail.

If you change you url to `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/javastudy` your container Java application can access the MySQL running on the host. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) post for a thorough explanation.

However, to make it work both running locally, so from Intellij and from the container, you can use different spring-boot profiles. Let's say `application-local.proeprties` which only contains `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javastudy` which will override the url if you use that profile