# docker run => throw error "connection error MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN"

Tags: node.js, docker

when I run it alone or together, there are no errors in my frontend and backend parts and they work as I want.and now I want to use docker, but when I try a error appears. I tried to solve with a previous solution that wrote before, but doesn't work., I create my Docker file and I type "docker build ." and this works
[image]

then [image]
I type docker run *Image Id*

Error

```
PS D:\javascript_projects\nimble_dersleri\backend> docker run 880a0a3e9b21

> ders-6@1.0.0 start
> node .bin/www

(node:18) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in '/package.json' of 'service.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
started listening on 3000
connection error MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db
    at Connection.openUri (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:819:32)
    at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:378:10
    at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1223:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:377:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/routes/mongo-connection.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'db:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db
    at Connection.openUri (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:819:32)
    at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:378:10
    at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1223:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:377:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/routes/mongo-connection.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'db:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'db:27017',
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1358575,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db
            at connectionFailureError (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:382:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.6.0
```

mongo-connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var db = mongoose.connection

mongoose.connect('mongodb://db:27017/week6');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console,'connection error'))

db.once('open',function(){
    console.log('we are connected to mongodb!')
})
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.6-alpine3.15 

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: `docker run` on its own isn't enough; you need to make sure your application and database containers are on the same Docker network.  See _e.g._ [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname) for details.

Comment: (`docker build` should never produce a PNG file as its output; if the output of the build step is important to the question, you might [edit] the question to replace the image file with the plain-text output of the build command.)

Comment: I don't understand very well, I need to read your link, but it needs to be edited, so can you edit it .