# Docker connect to localhost on a another container

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, dockerfile

I have 2 containers one running on **localhost:3001** and the other on **localhost:3003**

container localhost:3001 hits an endpoint thats running in the container localhost:3003
But gets a *(failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*

I have tried multiple ways to get them to connect. Please don't tell me to setup a docker compose file. I should be able to spin up 2 containers and have them communicate with their ports.

I also tried adding a network.

```
docker network create my-network

Shows as: ea26d2eaf604   my-network   bridge    local
```

Then I spin up both containers with the flag --net my-network.
When container localhost:3001 hits an endpoint thats running in the container localhost:3003 again I get a (failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

This is driving me crazy. What am I doing wrong here ?

I have even used shell to run a curl from localhost:3001 to localhost:3003 and I get

```
to curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3003 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker almost always means "the current container".  Imagine connecting two separate physical computers to the same wired or wireless network; even though they're on the same network, each thinks itself is `localhost` and you'd use the other system's DNS name to connect to it.  In Docker, see for example [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname/35184695#35184695).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place both machines on the same network, they are able to reference each other by their service/container name. (not localhost - as localhost is a local loopback on each container). Using a dedicated network would be the ideal way to connect from container to container.

I suspect what is happening in your case is that you are exposing 3001 from `container a` on the host, and 3003 from `container b` on the host. These ports are then open on the host, and from the host you can use `localhost`, however, from the containers to access the host you should use `host.docker.internal` which is a reference to the host machine, instead of using `localhost`

Here is some further reading about `host.docker.internal`
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds-for-all-platforms

**Update: docker-compose example**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  express1:
    image: node:latest
    networks:
      - my-private-network
    working_dir: /express
    command: node express-entrypoint.js
    volumes:
      - ./path-to-project1:/express

  express2:
    image: node:latest
    networks:
      - my-private-network
    working_dir: /express
    command: node express-entrypoint.js
    volumes:
      - ./path-to-project2:/express
  
networks:
  my-private-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.31.27.0/24
```

Then you can reference each container by their service name, e.g: from `express1` you can ping `express2`

Comment: I'm not exposing anything but my express server in container a is running on localhost:3001 and the other container b is on localhost:3003. I even tried just one container running localhost:3001 and then running my other express server from my host machine instead of docker and then using host.docker.internal instead of localhost but that didnt work.

Comment: 2 ways to go about it. First way involves more understanding (which is to set them up on their network, and use their respective host names/ip addresses. You can provide a hostname with `--hostname` .  The 2nd way which will be slightly easier to understand is to expose your ports on the host and use `host.docker.internal`

Comment: Using docker-compose to setup your containers may make this a lot easier.  You can setup the network within docker-compose, add the containers to the network, and then reference the containers by their `service` name that you have provided - I usually do this.

Comment: Ok lets take the easy way until I understand this. expose your ports on the host ? How do I do this ?

Comment: Do you mean adding EXPOSE 3001 to my dockerfile

Comment: You can use `-p` as part of docker run.    `docker run -p 3001:3001 my_image`, that will expose port 3001 of the container as port 3001 on your host

Comment: What is command: node express-entrypoint.js ? I already have my images built do I need this ? Cant i just use image: myImage

Comment: You just posted docker-compose.yml so why you saying docker run -p 3001:3001 my_image ? Shouldn't it just be docker-compose up

Comment: `-p` is if you are not using docker-compose.   Yes you can do just docker-compose up.  yes if your image is setup already, you can remove the `volumes` and `command` and `working_dir`

Comment: I have my urls setup in my env file which I have working with your code above. would I need to change them to AUTH_AUTHORIZATION_URL=http://express2:3003/authorize
AUTH_TOKEN_URL=http://express2:3003/token
AUTH_CALLBACK_URL=http://express1:3001/callback

Comment: If they are being requested from within the containers, yes, that would be required. Sounds like you're getting there.

Comment: I still have to use localhost:3001 to start the app in my browser. But when my express app running inside the container hits http://express2:3003/authorize it fails and just hangs

Comment: I tried a curl from inside exprerss1 to talk to express2 curl http://express2:3003/authorize
curl: (7) Failed to connect to express2 port 3003 after 9 ms: Connection refused

Comment: The problem may then be that the express server is listening on the local loopback. Try set the host that express listens to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: I changed both servers to app.listen(3001, "0.0.0.0"); and app.listen(3003, "0.0.0.0"); still the same enter the site on http://localhost:3001/ then it tries to hit the  express2:3003/authorize and hangs and eventualls fails as it can't connect