# Launch a docker images of postgres and an app in the same network?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking

I'm a new user of docker I have build my app and now I want to test the image of my app with postgres since it using a postgres Database. I'm using a postgres image too.

This is my image:

> docker images
>
> REPOSITORY            TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
>
> my_app             2.5-SNAPSHOT   6416734dcf5a   53 years ago   518MB

This is how i launch postgres:

```
docker run --name my-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

I tried to run my_app  like this:

```
 docker run --name my-app --link my-postgres:postgres -p 8080:8080 -d 6416734dcf5a
```

But i got this error:

> org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database:
>
> Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> SQL State  : 08001
>
> Error Code : 0
>
> Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

I was wondering if there is a way to launch my_app in a network, so that I can avoid this error.

Comment: The problem is the connection string you provided in your application container. You provided `localhost`, but `localhost` means this container, so in your case your application looks for a database in my_app container, and you need to change it. Also, if the database container is a basic database container that you have build from scratch, then you might need to configure `listen_addresses` and `pg_hba` settings.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname/35184695#35184695) in particular walks through the steps of creating a network and attaching both containers to it.  You should not use `docker run --link` on modern Docker, and the other container will not be `localhost`.