# Using Nginx reverse proxy in Docker to proxy other docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having some trouble getting my nginx container to forward traffic to other running containers. Note:: not using compose due to deployment constraints

For reference, I'm running things like:

```bash
docker run \
  --name oqm_infra_jaeger \
  -p 8090:16686 \
  -p 8091:14268 \
  -p 8096:4317 \
  -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true \
  -d jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.42
```

```bash
docker run \
  --name nginx \
  -p=80:80 \
  --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
  -v /etc/oqm/serviceConfig/infra/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/\
  -v /etc/oqm/serviceConfig/infra/nginx/conf.other.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.other.d/\
  nginx
```

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
upstream infra-jaeger {
    server host.docker.internal:8090;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location /infra/jaeger/ {
        proxy_pass http://infra-jaeger/;
        #proxy_redirect http://infra-jaeger/ /;

        proxy_redirect    off;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
        
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host/infra/jaeger;
        sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/infra/jaeger/';
        sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/infra/jaeger/';
        sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/infra/jaeger/';
        sub_filter_once off;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.other.d/proxy_params;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/conf.other.d/proxy_params` (in this dir to make it easy for docker volumes):

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Below are my attempts, and what went wrong:

- ```
  location /infra/jaeger/ {
       proxy_pass http://infra-jaeger/infra/jaeger/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_redirect https://infra-jaeger/ /;
  }
  ```

  Can reach service, request for page itself is `200`, but resources on page are stuck as they request `/image.svg` instead of `/infra/jaeger/image.svg`
- ```
  location /infra/jaeger/ {
       proxy_pass http://infra-jaeger/;

       proxy_redirect    off;
       add_header Pragma "no-cache";
       add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";

       proxy_set_header Host $http_host/infra/jaeger;
       sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter_once off;

       include /etc/nginx/conf.other.d/proxy_params;
  }
  ```

  Cannot reach service, `400`, reporting "400 Bad Request: malformed Host header"
- ```
  location /infra/jaeger/ {
       proxy_pass $scheme://infra-jaeger/;
       #proxy_redirect http://infra-jaeger/ /;

       # tell backend that message compression not allowed
       proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

       sub_filter_types *;
       sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'action="./'  'action="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'href="./'  'href="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter 'src="./'  'src="/infra/jaeger/';
       sub_filter_once off;

       #add_header Pragma "no-cache";
       #add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";

       include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       include /etc/nginx/conf.other.d/proxy_params;
   }
  ```

  Loads initial page, seems to replace url's, but all loaded resources (css, js) load the main html page instead of the actual css/js content???

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to run all of the containers on the same Docker network, as in [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname).  This is one of a couple of things Compose sets up automatically for you.

Comment: I don't think this is my issue, though I think it is something I want to do. Connectivity is currently there, just not quite right on the proxying