# docker network create --attachable does not work

Tags: windows, docker

I have two containers that I created this way:

1. `docker run --name db --network skainet -p 3306:3306`
2. `docker run --name backend --network skainet -p 8000:8000 -w /app -v C:/Users/kam/Documents/programming/espartanv2/fastapi:/app -d -it python bash`

and I wish they could talk to each other

```
docker network create --attachable skainet
```

and use

```
docker network connect skainet db
docker network connect skainet backend
```

but it doesn't update the container field

```
docker network inspect skainet
[
    {
        "Name": "skainet",
        "Id": "ca86014cad94cb4b32c524e05c96f4427619bf802891de3620d040c1486b5ed5",
        "Created": "2024-01-24T02:31:45.598491155Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.21.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I expected both containers to connect although I have had problems from the beginning even creating the containers and I have not been able to understand what is needed

Comment: I don't think I've seen that `--attachable` option before; assuming you've run `docker network create skainet` first, the two `docker run` commands should use the same network and the two containers can talk to each other (see for example [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname)).  When `backend` tries to talk to `db`, what configuration are you using, what code makes the connection, and what results to do you get?