# How can I set up a Docker network with restricted communication?

Tags: networking, docker, containers

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image: Docker Network Architecture]

The *server* containers each have port 8080 exposed, and accept requests from the client, but crucially, they are **not** allowed to communicate with each other.

The problem here is that the *server* containers are launched after the client container, so I can't pass container link flags to the client like I used to, since the containers it's supposed to link to don't exist yet.

I've been looking at the newer Docker networking stuff, but I can't use a bridge because I don't want server cross-communication to be possible. It also seems to me like one bridge per server doesn't scale well, and would be difficult to manage within the client container.

Is there some kind of switch-like docker construct that can do this?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why can't you use link?

Comment: In addition, could you provide some examples such as docker-compose files or any other script you use to orchestrate all your containers?

Comment: I can't use link because Servers are launched after the Client, so I can't link the Client to servers that don't exist yet, as the link info is passed on start, and you can't link retrospectively (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324860/how-to-create-a-bidirectional-link-between-containers). If it was one server, and many clients, I could pass link info to the clients, but I want the reverse.

Comment: I'm using Dockerode to interface with Docker through the Docker Remote API, but same goes for launching containers command line and using the flags. Right now I'm just using a network, but it's not ideal because I don't want the Servers connected to that network to be able to communicate with each other. I'm looking into iptables rules.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to "launch" the client containers before the server. But anyway, you could create the containers first and start them once the servers are available. Note that the `docker run` command is a sequence of `docker create` and `docker start` commands.

Comment: That's just the nature of my application; the client runs forever, the servers come and go over time. I don't ever actually use `run` since it doesn't play well with private registries, but link/net info is passed through `start` anyway so it makes no difference.

Comment: I see ... do you think a sort of whitelist set in your servers could work? Also you can use bind ips and or ACL rules

Comment: Actually, nvm my last statement, it can be passed in create too, but unfortunately that won't help because the servers need to be able to start long after the client.

Comment: I'd ideally like the servers to be "platform-independent", so any kind of whitelist would need to be outside, but even in that case it seems that the Docker side might get hairy (one network per server?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you will need to create multiple bridge networks, one per container. To simplify that, you may want to use `docker-compose` to specify how the networks and containers should be provisioned, and have the `docker-compose` tool wire it all up correctly.

### Resources:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2

---

**One more side note:** I *think* that exposed ports are accessible to all networks. If that's right, you may be able to set all of the server networking to none and rely on the exposed ports to reach the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is relevant to your use-case - I'm attempting to draw context regards your actual application from the diagram and comments. I'd recommend you go the **Service Discovery** route. It may involve a little bit of simple API over a central store (say Redis, or SkyDNS), but would make things simple in the long run.

Kubernetes, for instance, uses SkyDNS to do so with DNS. At the end of the day, any orchestration tool of your choice would most likely do something like this out of the box: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns

The idea is simple:

- Use a DNS container that keeps entries of newly spawned servers
- Allow the Client Container to query it for a list of servers. e.g. Picture a DNS response with a bunch of `server-<<ISO Timestamp of Server Creation>>`s
- Disallow client containers read-access to this DNS (how to manage this permission-configuration without indirection, i.e. without proxying through an endpoint that allows writing into the DNS Container, but not reading, *is* going to exotic)

Bonus Edit: I just realised you can use a simpler Redis-like setup to do this, and that DNS might just be overengineering :)

Comment: How does this prevent servers from communicating with each other? I don't imagine you'd proxy all traffic through the DNS container? Why couldn't a server just scan for other servers by itself?